# Why isn't my printer listed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing

Why is my printer not listed when using the lsusb command?

I've got a HP Photosmart C4780 connected via USB on Ubuntu 12.04. I've installed hplip but I still but this does not appear to have solved the problem. The printer does not show up in the printers listed.

How can I add the printer?

Thanks.

Edit - using dmesg | tail -f:

Before connecting the printer

```
[15358.944014] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[15359.015787] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
[15359.119684] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[15359.191166] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
[15359.223171] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15359.354968] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15359.530444] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
[15359.562288] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15359.694434] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15359.797753] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 4
```

After plugging in:

```
[15498.352933] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[15498.424509] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci_hcd
[15498.528717] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[15498.600251] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci_hcd
[15498.632144] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15498.763804] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15498.939336] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci_hcd
[15498.971263] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15499.103217] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[15499.206663] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 4
```

Comment: Can you [edit] and add the tail end of a `dmesg` after unplugging and plugging in the printer?

Comment: @Paul edited the question.

Comment: I've seen this behavior with USB devices that need more power than the USB port is capable of delivering. Adding a powered USB hub between the printer and the computer will generally improve the situation.

Comment: @devon.c.miller Unlikely, since the printer must be powered externally?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo lsusb` and/or different USB ports?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain You would think, wouldn't you? I have most recently encountered this with an externally powered Seagate FreeAgent USB hard drive that simply will not respond correctly unless I use a hub.